# Why are the tests faiing when the actual value and the expected value are the same in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing a code about reversing a String in Java and I have to do some tests with JUnit. The program works for every input I insert. The problem is the tests fail. However, when I see the actual and the expected values they're one and the same.

That is the code I wrote for the reversing method:

```java
public static String reverseEnd(String text, int start) {
    char[] reverse = new char[text.length()];
    char[] normal = new char[start];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (i < start) {
            normal[i] = text.charAt(i);
        }
        else {
            reverse[text.length()-i-1] = text.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return String.copyValueOf(normal) + String.copyValueOf(reverse);
}
```

And these are the tests I am doing:

```java
public void test2() {
    assertEquals("a", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("a", 1));
}

public void test4() {
    assertEquals("HdlroW ,olle", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("Hello, World",1));
}

//text.length() = 12
//start = 3 (1<start<text.length()-1)
//text.length() - start = 9
@Test
public void test5() {
    assertEquals("HeldlroW ,ol", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("Hello, World",3));
}

//text.length() = 12
//start = 11
//text.length() - start = 1 (= text.length() -1)
@Test
public void test6() {
    assertEquals("Hello, World", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("Hello, World",11));
}

//text.length() = 12
//start = 12
//text.length() - start = 0 
@Test
public void test7() {
    assertEquals("Hello, World", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("Hello, World",12));
}

//text.length() = 5
//start = 5
//text.length() - start = 0
@Test
public void test8() {
    assertEquals("World", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("World",0));
}

//text.length() = 5
//start = 4
//text.length() - start = 1
@Test
public void test9() {
    assertEquals("World", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("World",4));
}

//text.length() = 5
//start = 3
//text.length() - start = 2 (even and >1)
@Test
public void test10() {
    assertEquals("Wordl", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("World",3));
}

//text.length() = 5
//start = 2
//text.length() - start = 3
@Test
public void test11() {
    assertEquals("Wodlr", StringManipulation.reverseEnd("World",2));
}
```

Comment: Which tests are failing?  What is the error message when they fail?  Test frameworks will usually print useful messages on an error.  Are you sure that the test values are correct, II think I see a couple of errors.  When you test and have problems it helps to be methodical: start with reversing one character, then two, then three, etc. until you see a pattern to the errors and can decide how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual and expected values you're getting a **not** the same. The actual values your method returns have trailing whitespaces. One way to get rid of them would be to `trim` your result:

```java
return String.copyValueOf(normal).trim() + String.copyValueOf(reverse).trim();
```

Alternatively, instead of messing around with arrays, you could use a `StringBuilder` to append the characters you need:

```java
public static String reverseEnd(String text, int start) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    sb.append(text, 0, start);
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= start; --i) {
        sb.append(text.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```